# Can an Android or IOS app make a new bluetooth connection with no user prompts?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I'm working on an app that will talk to certain pieces of hardware via bluetooth.
The app will know the bluetooth password for each hardware device, and know which one you are currently near.
So, even if the phone has never made a connection to a specific device before, it is possible to have my app establish a bluetooth session without prompting the user?
So the user could just press the "connect" button to establish the bluetooth connection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953413/bluetooth-connect-without-pairing - depends what you mean by "talk" with Bluetooth.

Comment: Generally, "talk" means pass data back and forth.  Kinda like what bluetooth does.
In this case, I'd probably be using the serial data stream emulation.

Comment: I know what talk means in general, and I'm familiar with Bluetooth programming, nice response. Bluetooth has different modes, and secure vs insecure channels, and a specification. Maybe you should check out the docs and the spec, or do a basic search here for communicating without pairing.

Comment: I have done bluetooth before as well on Android. (not on IOS though)
I had never realized you COULD do it without Pairing, as the previous device I worked with required pairing.

Comment: Okay, found the answer in another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945171/bluetooth-connection-without-pairing

I can hope that technique will work on IOS.